# How to add Files to queue and how can we retrieve them one after another in android

Tags: android, queue

Hi i am new for android and in my app i have HLSDownloader_Manager class for downloading files individually

But according to my requirement files what i want to download which are first need to add queue and download one after another can some one help me please

### HLSDownloader_Manager:-

```
 private void startDownload() {

        mDownloadingThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                    switch (downloadingState) {

                        case DN_STATE_COMPLETED:
                            mLastStatus = DownloadStatus.COMPLETE;
                            updateDownloadListener();
                            break;

                        case DN_STATE_ERROR:
                            mLastStatus = DownloadStatus.STOPPED;
                            updateDownloadListener();
                            break;
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        };
        mDownloadingThread.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know your exact implementation and requirement but a generic solution is to Insert your incoming file download request in queue data structure and if it is a first request that means your queue is empty then start downloading this file, all subsequent request should be queued and on completion of every downloading request just poll your next file download request from queue and so on until it gets emptied.

something like this...

```
Queue queue = new LinkedList();

private void startDownload() {
    Thread downloadingThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                ((Thread)queue.poll()).start();
            }
        }
    };


    if (queue.isEmpty()) {
        downloadingThread.start();
    }
    else {
        queue.add(downloadingThread);
    }
}
```

Further reading:
[Queue Interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue.html),
[Queue Implementations in Java.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html)